# Paypal Platform Fee not received to partner account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Im integrating Paypal marketplace solution and i've been going thourgh the API documentations for a while.

The steps that i did are the following:

- Create an account
- Create partner refferal url and sign in as a seller.
- Create an order with the payee object and with the platform fee

The order api that i did is the following

```
    {
"intent": "CAPTURE",
"purchase_units": [{
  "amount": {
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "value": "1500.00"
  },
  "payee": {
    "email_address": "sb-ipkq327298975@business.example.com"
  },
  "payment_instruction": {
    "disbursement_mode": "INSTANT",
    "platform_fees": [{
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "450.00"
      }
    }]
  }
}]
}
```

After using another sandbox account and paying the 1500$ value, i was able to see the amount send in the seller dashboard with the fees taken out.
However when i check the dashboard of the partner account, no money has been sent.

I have been following Paypal's multiparty payment and specifically the following documentation:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/checkout/immediate-capture/

But im stuck at the part that the platform fee is nowhere to be found.

Can this be happening because of sandbox mode? If so how can i be sure that the money will be sent to the partner account once im on live mode.

Comment: I dont think stackoverflow is the right place for this, you should ask paypal support instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal platform fees are never deposited in any PayPal account.

In the live environment, platform fees are deposited in the platform's bank account (not PayPal account) once per day.

In the sandbox environment, platform fees go nowhere.